# trying to allow domain admins access in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, centos5

I am trying to authenticate domain admins through apache and it is not working. Error i get is as follows

```
[Mon Sep 24 14:54:45 2012] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1432): [client 172.16.0.85] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Mon Sep 24 14:54:45 2012] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(915): [client 172.16.0.85] Using HTTP/intranet.xxx.com@xxx.COM as server principal for password verification
[Mon Sep 24 14:54:45 2012] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(655): [client 172.16.0.85] Trying to get TGT for user sharifu@xxx.COM
[Mon Sep 24 14:54:45 2012] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(569): [client 172.16.0.85] Trying to verify authenticity of KDC using principal HTTP/intranet.xxx.com@xxx.COM
[Mon Sep 24 14:54:45 2012] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(994): [client 172.16.0.85] kerb_authenticate_user_krb5pwd ret=0 user=sharifu@xxx.COM authtype=Basic
[Mon Sep 24 14:54:45 2012] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(561): [client 172.16.0.85] ldap authorize: Creating LDAP req structure
[Mon Sep 24 14:54:45 2012] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(573): [client 172.16.0.85] auth_ldap authorise: User DN not found, LDAP: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed
```

Below is what I have in my httpd file

```
Alias /compass "/data/intranet/html/compass"

<Directory "/data/intranet/html/compass">
        AuthType Kerberos
        AuthName KerberosLogin
        KrbServiceName HTTP/intranet.xxx.com
        KrbMethodNegotiate On
        KrbMethodK5Passwd On
        KrbAuthRealms xxx.COM
        Krb5KeyTab /etc/httpd/conf/intranet.keytab
       # require valid-user
       # Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       # AllowOverride All
       # Order allow,deny
       # Allow from all
       #        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE


# taken from http://blogs.freebsdish.org/tmclaugh/2010/07/15/mod_auth_kerb-ad-and-ldap-authorization/
# download extra module and install

        # Strip the kerberos realm from the principle.
#   MapUsernameRule (.*)@(.*) "$1"

        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://echo.uk.xxx.com akhutan.usa.xxx.com/dc=xxx,dc=com?sAMAccountName"
        AuthLDAPBindDN cn=Administrator,ou=Users,dc=xxx,dc=com
        AuthLDAPBindPassword ***
        Require ldap-group cn=Domain Admins,ou=Users,dc=xxx,dc=com
</Directory>
```

I have followed this [guide](http://blogs.freebsdish.org/tmclaugh/2010/07/15/mod_auth_kerb-ad-and-ldap-authorization/). I have download and install the tarball. when I try to uncomment `MapUsernameRule`  i get failed error when restarting apache

```
Reloading httpd: not reloading due to configuration syntax error
```

I am using centos 5 64bit.

I have added the following line but i still get syntax error

```
LoadModule mod_map_user modules/mod_map_user.so

httpd: Syntax error on line 199 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `mod_map_user' in file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_map_user.so: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_map_user.so: undefined symbol: mod_map_user
[root@hero mod_map_user]# ll /etc/httpd/modules/mod_map_user.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39444 Sep 24 16:23 /etc/httpd/modules/mod_map_user.so
```

I have updated the `load module` part and it works now, how ever it is still not working for me. Error i get is as follows

```
[Mon Sep 24 17:19:05 2012] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1432): [client 172.16.0.85] kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
[Mon Sep 24 17:19:05 2012] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(915): [client 172.16.0.85] Using HTTP/intranet.xxx.com@xxx.COM as server principal for password verification
[Mon Sep 24 17:19:05 2012] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(655): [client 172.16.0.85] Trying to get TGT for user sharifu@xxx.COM
[Mon Sep 24 17:19:05 2012] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(569): [client 172.16.0.85] Trying to verify authenticity of KDC using principal HTTP/intranet.xxx.com@xxx.COM
[Mon Sep 24 17:19:05 2012] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(994): [client 172.16.0.85] kerb_authenticate_user_krb5pwd ret=0 user=sharifu@xxx.COM authtype=Basic
[Mon Sep 24 17:19:05 2012] [info] [client 172.16.0.85] Applying pattern '^(.*)@(.*)$' to user 'sharifu@xxx.COM', mech:'Any'
[Mon Sep 24 17:19:05 2012] [info] [client 172.16.0.85] Pattern matched
[Mon Sep 24 17:19:05 2012] [notice] [client 172.16.0.85] User name 'sharifu@xxx.COM' rewritten to 'sharifu'
[Mon Sep 24 17:19:05 2012] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(561): [client 172.16.0.85] ldap authorize: Creating LDAP req structure
[Mon Sep 24 17:19:05 2012] [debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(573): [client 172.16.0.85] auth_ldap authorise: User DN not found, LDAP: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed
```

httdp conf ffile now has:

```
Alias /compass "/data/intranet/html/compass"

<Directory "/data/intranet/html/compass">
        AuthType Kerberos
        AuthName KerberosLogin
        KrbServiceName HTTP/intranet.xxx.com
        KrbMethodNegotiate On
        KrbMethodK5Passwd On
        KrbAuthRealms xxx.COM
        Krb5KeyTab /etc/httpd/conf/intranet.keytab
       # require valid-user
       # Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       # AllowOverride All
       # Order allow,deny
       # Allow from all
       #        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# taken from http://blogs.freebsdish.org/tmclaugh/2010/07/15/mod_auth_kerb-ad-and-ldap-authorization/
# download extra module and install

        # Strip the kerberos realm from the principle.
        MapUsernameRule (.*)@(.*) "$1"

        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://echo.uk.xxx.com akhutan.usa.xxx.com/cn=users,dc=xxx,dc=com?sAMAccountName"
        AuthLDAPBindDN cn=Administrator,ou=users,dc=xxx,dc=com
        AuthLDAPBindPassword xxx
        Require ldap-group cn=Domain Admins,ou=users,dc=xxx,dc=com
</Directory>
```

Comment: Try running `apachectl configtest`, see if it says anything more specific about the error.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Modules are commonly named "map_user_module", so the line might be `LoadModule map_user_module modules/mod_map_user.so`. I'm not sure if CentOS messes with this default (many of the Linux distros screw with Apache, I can't remember them all).

Comment: updated question

Comment: working now, i had mixup with ou and cn

Comment: Your `AuthLDAPBindDN` line is wrong (assuming you're using Active Directory). There is no `OU=Users`, Users is a special folder, you'd reference it by `CN=Users`. So the line should be `AuthLDAPBindDN CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com`. Side note: you really shouldn't be using the Administrator account (you should create a service account of some kind just for this server, MS recommends `Apache$httpd$server01`, replace server name as appropriate); and the Administrator account *should* be renamed (not Admin or root either; but just about anything else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris S has mentioned my AuthLDAPBindDN was wrong